# Lead status touchpoints

Tags: leads

I need to track the lead status has at least 3 touch points within 20 days. The lead status should have changed at least 3 times within 20 days. If the status is not changed we need to send the lead owner an email.. How could we handle this?

Comment: What are your possible status values?  Is it possible for a Lead to progress only one-way (towards customer)?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a batch class to handle this. Get all the lead records whose status is != Closed. Track the field "Status" on lead. Then get all the records of lead history object where a change is made on status field in last 20 days. Have two FOR loops to first iterate over leads and inner loop to iterate over lead history. Have a variable to store the number of times a lead has the record of "Lead History" in the inside FOR loop and increment it by one each time a record is found. Then check if count is less than 3 then send an email to that lead owner.

You can schedule this batch to run at you preferable specific time daily.

Regards!
Ruchi

Comment: What would the Database.getQueryLocator be that you would return from the start method in your batch class?

Comment: was confused with that only.. Not having clarity

Comment: @martin : It would be Lead object records.

Comment: You're right. I thought you missed a step, but I was using the wrong name for the Lead History child relationship.